# Opening multiple GUI windows in MATLAB at the same time?

Tags: matlab

I am very new to MATLAB so this might be quite obvious, but I can't find a solution. I am using a MATLAB toolbox called MatCont. When opening the GUI provided by this toolbox, multiple windows open. Everytime I switch to another window (say - my browser), I have to reopen these GUI windows one by one.

Is there any way to get MATLAB to associate these windows into one configuration and make it easy to open the GUI in one click?

Comment: Are you able to get a list of figure handles to these windows from the toolbox? If so, you could probably modify the callback properties of the windows and modify their behaviour. Otherwise, this might be a bit difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two rather obvious possibilities spring to mind:

1. Dock the windows within Matlab itself. When you want to switch back to your Matlab session and view the toolbox windows, all you need to do is switch back to Matlab.
2. Just minimize the browser window to the taskbar. The windows opened by your Matlab session should then return to the foreground.

In addition, since this kind of question is very much system dependent, it might help if you'd specify precisely what operating system and/or window manager you're using.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. Well only one of the windows of this toolbox seems dockable. Your second idea has come to mind but I often have several windows.

I use windows 7 in this case, but I could switch to ubuntu if this gets really annoying. Its kind of a minor issue though so I can live with it.

Thanks anyway